# AWS loadbalancer does not route traffic properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to use one loadbalancer between two different clusters, I've add two subdomains in `Route 53` and I also created two different `target groups` which one them indicates staging environment and one of them indicates production environment, but when I enter the relevant url of each of it always shows production environment, It's because request cannot get routed. actually it does the `default action` which is rule number three.

Any help would be welcome!
Thank you so much!

[image: 1]

Comment: From what you posted, there is nothing wrong in your rules. have you tried different browser? How did you set your Route53 records?

Comment: I've created two subdomains and both of their values are this one load balancer.

Comment: I don't know how! but for some reasons it is working now! thanks.

Comment: I think just needed maybe to wait for DNS refresh. Anyway, I will provide a short answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The listener rules provided in the question are **correct** and they should work as expected. In fact, after waiting a bit, the domain names and the ALB started to work, which suggest that maybe and DNS  or browser caches needed to update before it started working.